# AWS Athena: A Way to Solve this OOP loop/dynamic SQL type problem (or a better approach?)

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

Table:

| SKU | Amount | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 4 | 2022-02-20 | 2022-05-17 |
| A | 2 | 2022-05-18 | 2099-12-31 |
| B | 11 | 2022-04-14 | 2099-12-31 |

The following query allows me to put in any date and get the amount per sku on that date

```
select  SKU, Amount
from    myTable
where   date('2022-04-30') between start_date and end_date;
```

Results:

| SKU | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| A | 4 |
| B | 11 |

Note that we have 4 for SKU A because 2022-04-30 is between 2022-02-20 and 2022-05-17 (the first record).

but if the query had:

```
 where  date('2023-01-01') between start_date and end_date;
```

Then we would get an amount of 2 for SKU A (The second record is "chosen"(2022-05-18 to 2099-12-31))

But I want this for every month. So I just need a way to run this query for each date (unless you have a better approach)

AWS Athena does not support dynamic sql, so that's not an option

I could of course just copy paste the query, change the year/month, and `UNION` the results, but then I would have `12*years*lines` of code. This would be tedious and seems like a very bad practice (imagine if I needed it at a finer grain)

I was able to get a list of the dates I want with the following query:

```
with oneRowPerMonth as(
select sequence(date('2019-01-15'), date('2030-01-15'), interval '1' month) as seq
)
select date_trunc('month', date(midMonth)) + interval '1' month - interval '1' day as LastDayOfMonth
from oneRowPerMonth
cross join unnest(seq) as t(midMonth)
```

...but that's as far as I've made it.

Obviously when I have multiple months I will need a date column... so I'm trying to get to something like this:

| SKU | Amount | Date of Record |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 4 | 2022-04-30 |
| B | 11 | 2022-04-30 |
| A | 2 | 2022-05-31 |
| B | 11 | 2022-05-31 |
| A | 2 | 2022-06-31 |
| B | 11 | 2022-06-31 |
| ... | ... | ... |

Comment: Answer deleted pending further clarification.

Comment: Why do you have `A 2 2022-05-31` row? It should be `A 6 2022-05-31` cause there are two records for this month. Or please explain the logic.

Comment: @Gron Stron - It's not a SUM, the amount is a snapshot. 

On 2022-05-17 the first record's end date was updated from 2099-12-31 to 2022-05-17 as well as a new record being inserted with 2022-05-17 as the start date, and 2099-12-31 as the end date. 

It doesn't matter when the records are. The last record could have a start date of 2022-12-05, and if you queried for 2040-07-01 you would still see A = 2 b/c it's before the end date of 2099-12-31.

Comment: Generating the months was the wrong approach. The unnest comes with all sorts of limitations. My colleague suggested using our dim_date which actually made this pretty easy